# How to autowire httpsession without server

Tags: java, spring, httpsession

I have a common class `K` which autowires `HttpSession`.
This class gets extended:

- `A extends K`
- `B extends K`

Now class `A` needs `HttpSession` which will run as web application in tomcat server

But `B` does not need to run on server, as it has batch jobs. So `HttpSession` not required..

While running `B` with main program it throws exception nobeandef found for httpsession.

Comment: What do you mean  by `A` has a tomcat server? A tomcat server is a service which runs your application. Therefore a java class cannot "have" a tomcat server

Comment: We have two configurations..one for web application and other for batch...for batch server not required but we are using same java class

Comment: Edit your question and explain so that users can understand what you are asking

Comment: to add on @SAM 's comment, It is extremely difficult to understand what you are asking if you cannot provide stack traces, used frameworks etc. `HttpSession` can come from a variety of libraries, and each can be instantiated differently. Please add more detail to your question, especially an exception stack, as those provide loads of information.

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple of ways to avoid `B` requiring an `HttpSession`.  The simplest is to make the autowiring optional:

```
@Autowired(required = false)
```

This should do what you need, but has the side-effect that it's also no longer required for `A`.

The alternative would be to move the `@Autowired` to a setter method on `A` for the `HttpSession`.  This would keep the dependency required on `A`, but Spring would no longer see the need to try to wire it in for `B`.